# Issue to parse variable in jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

I am using the following code in my pipeline:

```
sh """
       if [[ "${line}" != *"="* ]]; then continue; fi
                ARGS+=( "--from-literal=${line%%=*}=${line#*=}" )
```

but I got "unexpected token: %=

Do you know how can I parse the following variables:
${line%%=*}=${line#*=}  in my jenkins pipeline?

Comment: Use \ (backslash) to escape the special characters.

Comment: @SouravAtta you mean \${line%%=*} ?

Comment: Yes and also, escape the % and = also

Comment: @SouravAtta it dosen't work. I get : groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: line for class: groovy.lang.Binding
 at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)